# filling missing data in pandas data set

Tags: python, pandas

I have annual stock data and some of the years, datas are missing for the columns : at, ebit, lt , ni, re, wcap.

How can I fill these missing slots with the data of the first year where these metrics are available?

[image: dataframe]

Comment: Please post your data as text, rather than an image.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your `fyear` is sorted, you can try `ffill` then `bfill`

```py
df = df.ffill().bffil()
```